# Convert string to datetime with T and z format

Tags: json, datetime

I have a json with string value as '2018-02-12T23:15:08z'. I want to convert it to apex. How can i convert this to datetime? Thanks

Comment: please update your post with what you have attempted so far, thanks

Answer (score 3):

JSON.deserialize should be able to handle this:

```
DateTime result = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize('"'+jsonDate+'"', DateTime.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm

Use the newInstance method that you need, and parse the string into that.